# How to boost current through encoder/decoder ICs?

Tags: led, display

This is my first electronics project in 15 years and I have clearly forgotten everything I learned in all my electrical engineering courses in college. I hope this question isn't too ignorant.

I'm building a pretty simple but very large (25'x15') array of LEDs to show a bitmap. I will probably end up with 40x25 LEDs given the spacing we have.  I am currently looking at using 20-30ma blue (~4.5V) LEDs.

I'm doing what I guess is a typical setup where LEDs sit at grid intersections and along the edges I drive a horizontal line and sink a vertical line in pairs in a fast scanning algorithm from a cheap processor to render the bitmap. To reduce wiring I'll be putting decoders (3-8 demultipliers) every 8 lines. Easy stuff.

The problem is this: all the decoders I can find (74*138 / 74*238) can handle 5-8mA of current.

Am I just looking at the wrong parts, or do I need to add an additional part at each 8-line module to boost the output, like a buffer? I barely even know the right words to use, it is so long since I've done this.

Comment: Are you handling brightness by varying pulse length?

Comment: I might play with that but it's not a required part of the design. Right now I just want full-on or full-off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect to drive strings of LEDs from just digital logic outputs.  Use the logic outputs to drive transistors, then have the transistors drive the LED strings.

Comment: You could be more specific about how to drive the LED strings.  http://i91.photobucket.com/albums/k318/jtr1962/CPF/LED_Driver_1.gif http://rouvelle.com/ael_sp_11/ http://fieldlines.com/board/index.php/topic,131213.0.html

Comment: Thank you, I think I can go from here. I'm not driving strings of LED's, as only one will be lit at a time, but putting transistors in the way is what I was missing I think.

Answer (score 0):

`Am I just looking at the wrong parts?`
Maybe. For displays, there used to be *BCD to "decimal" decoder/driver*s (one-out-of-ten), several types for driving Nixie tubes (up to 60 V) or lamps (e.g. 74145: 80 mA, even in LS - funny \$V_{OL}\$ @80 mA, convincing @24 mA).

Then again, you'll need 15 or 25 times the LED current for the "decoded" dimension (5 mA in 2011…); you may choose to multiplex just 1:5.
Or just multiply the number of drivers/split the LED panel.
Or use dedicated drivers - there are integrated ones, ULN 2001… coming to mind, high side drivers, too.